# Empty UDP packet blocks UdpClient in Mono

Tags: c#, udp, mono

I have a small c# application to receive UDP packets. It's developped in .Net Framework 4.0. I need to run it in Windows and in Linux via Mono.

All works fine until I receive an empty UDP packet from network.

In Windows the UPDClient object reports 1 packet available and, if I read it, I have the empty payload.

Instead with Mono I don't have the empty payload and it seems that the UPDClient object blocks because after the empty packet I don't receive any data until I restart the application.

I tried with Mono 3.2.8 and also with 5.10.1.20.

Someone have the same problem?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Everyone should move to .NET 6 now.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think the problem is in Mono, not in .NET version

Comment: Mono is well known to behave different in various spots from .NET Framework on Windows, while .NET Core/.NET 6 aims to be consistent on all supported platforms. Since the whole ecosystem migrated to .NET Core in the past few years, you should follow the trend, instead of staying on Mono.